# Jquery-ui Tabs only work after page-refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My Jquery tabs work, but only after I refresh the page. See the images below for more information. What is causing this and more importantly, how can I solve this?

I am not getting any errors. I allready added:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#functions").tabs();
});
```

This is my order of code (Ruby, javascript.js)

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/tabs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**Code & View before: refresh**

[image: Code before refresh]
[image: View before refresh]

**Code & View after: refresh**

[image: Code after refresh]
[image: View after refresh]

Comment: If you post your code in jsFiddle or plnkr, that reproduces the problem, it is easy for people to provide some solution.

Comment: The code is oke, it's just not properly loaded or rendered. When I browser through the pages it's always the second visit that the pages arn't working. I noticed in my assets that the .css file isn't loaded the second time. After a refresh it's back.

Comment: It is hard to figure out what is wrong just by looking at the image and the DOM structure!

Comment: I was hoping it was a known problem/bug

Comment: At least, it is not known to me :)